# Flask css not updating

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am using Flask (the python Package) on my mac, when I first wrote my css it displayed ok. However when I updated it and tried to check it, I only see the first css styles. I have tried restarting the terminal, as well as reinstalling Flask. Any suggestions? Thanks.
Heres the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="logo">
            <center><img src="/static/img/p_logo.png" alt="pic"/></center>
        </div>
    </header> 

    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

</body>
```

And heres the CSS:

```
    * {
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

header {
background-color: #000000;
width: 100%;
height: 7px;

}
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant code?

Comment: ok, I updated it with css and html. Any other suggestions>

Comment: Did you try reloading the page using Shift + Ctrl + R? (This clears the browser's cache for the page.)

Comment: CMD (or CTRL on Windows) + SHIFT + R = success! Thank you.

Comment: I am also facing it..........This is a problem with the flask server...this should be addressed by the flask Team!!!

Comment: from datetime import timedelta

# setting cache time out 
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = timedelta(seconds=1)

or 
app.send_file_max_age_default = timedelta(seconds=1)

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error." No it wasn't, I just got a repro of this today, July 11th, 2019.

Comment: just come across this pain , and figured it out , you need to clear your browser cache , while searching for solving , i've come across `app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0` , might as wll give a try...clear your browser cache , than use that code below `app = Flask(__name__)`

Comment: I've just tried the code , and yup , it works like a charm , so the problem is `browser cache`...Clear your cache first , than use that code...and why is it closed tho

Comment: Ctrl + f5 is solution

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Problem is, as already said, related to browser cache.

To solve that, you could add some dynamic variable to your static (css, js) links. I prefer last modified timestamp for each file.

```
/static/css/style.css?q=1280549780
```

Here is a snippet for that:

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/40/

```
@app.context_processor
def override_url_for():
    return dict(url_for=dated_url_for)

def dated_url_for(endpoint, **values):
    if endpoint == 'static':
        filename = values.get('filename', None)
        if filename:
            file_path = os.path.join(app.root_path,
                                 endpoint, filename)
            values['q'] = int(os.stat(file_path).st_mtime)
    return url_for(endpoint, **values)
```

Comment: This is totally problematic to work with flask...is there any other solution??

Comment: It's not a problem inherent to Flask framework but browser caching. You could always disable browser cache by appropriate headers, but this is not a solution for production server.     _There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things._   -- Phil Karlton

Comment: Ive never had this problem with anything apart from flask

Comment: Jacek Kaniuk: Are you sure it's related to browser cache? When I install brand new browser, I have still the same problem. Yes, the first time I open the url, the .css files loaded are not the newest ones.

Comment: What do you mean by 'brand new browser'? Like reinstalling Chrome or something?

Comment: @culter Yes, it's related to browser cache. There are similarities to how the browsers cache css and js, so you'll find this problem appears in all browsers.

Comment: @DuncanWhyte By installing new browser, I mean install of a new web browser. Some browser, that was never installed on the OS in the past.

Comment: @Jason In my case it had nothing to do with browser cache. I opened 2 simultaneous SSH connections to the server via putty and that was the problem. When I closed one of them, everything worked fine.

Comment: Or you can return response header like stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066804/disabling-caching-in-flask

Comment: I had the same issue and it was a because Chrome was caching the old css. You can troubleshot by doing a hard reload on your browser tab. Also inspect the css file in Chrome to make sure it is having the expected content.

Comment: Just a note that your link is broken and it [doesn't look like they are going to bring snippets back](https://github.com/pallets/website/issues/41)

Comment: or else open it on incognito mode