# New CSS selectors added to the .css file are not working; using Flask and Bootstrap

Tags: python, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I'm using one of the Bootstrap examples (the Dashboard). I'm deploying the site using Python Flask.

The style.css file is being called successfully using Flask.

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename ='bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename ='ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename ='style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Everything works except when I add my own CSS selectors to the file and try to call them in HTML.

For example, I've added

```
#profile_picture {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
  -moz-border-radius: 150px;
}
.flash_msg {
  background: #93ff9e;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

to the style.css file, and

```
<img id="profile_picture" src="{{user[1]}}">

<li class="flask_msg">{{ message }}</li>
```

to the html, yet nothing happens.

Here is the [link to the full style.css](https://github.com/JTP709/SMS/blob/master/static/style.css) file.

Here is [one of the HTML templates](https://github.com/JTP709/SMS/blob/master/templates/incidents.html).

Here is t[he rest of the repo](https://github.com/JTP709/SMS).

Comment: Maybe a caching issue. Otherwise, can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You're right, it was a caching issue. I cleared the cache and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is looking for an img child of #profile_picture on your github.

Answer (score 0):

This was a caching issues. Clearing the browser cache allowed it to work. However, I believe this post may provide a better solution: [Flask css not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714653/flask-css-not-updating)